# Rails average - collect only if value <> 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using this code to calculate the average of some numbers - note that the `rankings` column is serialized and contains a hash:

```
@reviews.collect{|review| review.rankings[label].to_i}.sum.to_f/@reviews.length if @reviews.length > 0
```

The drawback with this code is this: if one of the values is `nil`, the average calculates as if it existed as a zero. The problem is basically that the `@reviews.length` denominator assumes every review has a relevant value.

How do I exclude from the denominator those reviews that don't count?

---

Thank you very much for your answers. The problem ended up being with the denominator, i.e. the `/@reviews.length` part. When I used `reject` on both numerator and denominator, the equation stopped dividing by total length and started dividing by (length - no of nils).

End result - 2 scores [0 and 100] average to 50; [nil and 100] average to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000258) to the rescue.

```
@reviews.reject{|review| review.rankings[label].nil?}.collect{|review| review.rankings[label].to_i}.sum.to_f/@reviews.length if @reviews.length > 0
```

Comment: Not quite but I managed to get it working as per my reply above. I'm accepting anyway. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with that approach (using `compact` to kill the `nil`s):

```
rankings = @reviews.map{ |review| review.rankings[label] }.compact
rankings.map(&:to_i).sum.to_f / rankings.count unless rankings.count == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if @reviews.length > 0
   @reviews.collect{|r| r.rankings[label]}.compact.map(&:to_f).sum / @reviews.length
  else
   0
  end
```